# How to use unmanaged C/C++ structs and functions

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr, wrapper

I have been given the task to figure out a way (if possible) to convert the low level processing portion of a commercial program written in C/C++  (more C then C++) into a managed library to be used with an updated program in C#. I have the full source code in Visual C++ 6.0 along with the DLL's and static libraries.

A must requirement is not to modify any of the C/C++ code - just somehow create a wrapper around it. I believe I will try to create a managed C++ DLL. There is an extensive use of structs and struct pointers in many functions.

Consider something like this from a C/C++ header file:

```
typedef struct {
   union {
       char *char_p;
       void *void_p;
   }
   int a;
   void *rsvd[16];
 } sample_struct;

int sample_func(sample_struct *struct_p, double x);
int sample_func(sample_struct *struct_p, double x, double y);
```

How can I wrap this to a CLR wrapper?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. I am even open to a different approach.

Thanks.

Comment: CLR environments have a mechanism called Platform Invoke, which will for the most part just let you call into native code directly. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: What's the question here? You haven't settled on a plan of action yet. C++/CLI calling existing DLLs? C++/CLI recompile source? P/invoke existing DLLs? Which is it to be.

Comment: After all the research, I am planning to C++/CLI recompile the source.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a wrapper ref struct first:
because managed c++ has no union, so use cp_valid as flag(cp or vp is valid).

```
ref struct wrapper_st {
    String^ cp;
    IntPtr^ vp;
    bool cp_valid;
    int a;
    array<IntPtr^>^ rsvd;
};
```

second, create wrapper function

```
int wrapper_func(wrapper_st ^st, double x)
{
    sample_struct t;
    char *pp = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(st->cp).ToPointer();
    if (st->cp_valid)
        t.char_p = pp;
    else
        t.void_p = st->vp->ToPointer();
    t.a = st->a;

    // must ensure st->rsvd is not null, and length is 16!!!
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        t.rsvd[i] = st->rsvd[i]->ToPointer();
    }
    int ret = sample_func(&t, x);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(pp));
    return ret;
}
```

then ,you can use wrapper function in c#

Comment: How do I wrap a simple int pointer? Essentially, convert a int ^ to a int *. Example C function: Add(int a, int b, int* sum) with the wrapper function: Add_wrapper(int a, int b, int ^sum).

Comment: I think an issue with this solution is that the unmanaged function might modify the value of a member of the struct, say "t.a". This is not reflected on the wrapper_st which maybe important

Comment: you can use pin_ptr to wrap a int pointer.  pin_ptr<int> pa = &t.a; int *native_pointer = pa; see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx)